# Python kernel still generates IP headers when sending ip raw packet

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am using the following code to send raw IP packet from MacOS.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
# s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
s.sendto(packet, dest_addr)
```

With the second line commented out, wireshark shows that the kernel is generating ip header and take the whole packet(which already includes an IP header) passed to s.sendto as the payload. The proto of the kernel generated IP header is 255, which is the value of
socket.IPPROTO_RAW.

If I uncommented the second line, it gives me an error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
and no packet is sent out.